# Manifest merger failed with multiple errors on kotlin project

Tags: android, github, kotlin

I have imported an image uploading library from github. But i got errors like manifest merger failed. Can someone help?

Here i shared the imported library

```
implementation "com.github.ChiliLabs:ChiliPhotoPicker:0.3.1"
```

Comment: Just go to manifest file and at bottom click on merger manifest there you can check for errors

Comment: @ShivamOberoi ok